# I interrupted a clone operation. How can I clone again without errors?

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04, moses

I ran

```
git clone https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder.git
```

and then pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. I then tried to clone again, but I got the following error:

```
fatal: destination path 'mosesdecoder' already exists and is not an empty directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Drop the directory and its contents